# Dynamically cast to function argument type (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting, dynamic-cast

In `f1()`, I want to be able to dynamically cast its `foo` argument to the same type as the argument of `f2()` (`Bar`, `Qux`, etc). Is this possible?

```cpp
struct Foo {
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
};
struct Bar : public Foo {};
struct Qux : public Foo {};

template<class T>
void f1(T f2, Foo &foo) {
  // dynamically cast foo to type of f2's argument?
  f2(dynamic_cast<Bar &>(foo));
}

int main() {
  Bar bar;
  Qux qux;
  f1([](Bar &bar) {}, bar);
  f1([](Qux &qux) {}, qux); // error here!
}
```

Comment: This is one of my favourite questions so far this year. It looks simple on the surface, but ...  no - and look at all the nice answers. +1 all around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for a templated conversion `operator`:

```
template <typename T>
struct dynamic_caster
{
    T *ptr;
    dynamic_caster(T &ref) : ptr(&ref) {}
    template <typename U>
    operator U &() const
    {
        return *dynamic_cast<std::remove_reference_t<U> *>(ptr);
    }
};

template<class T>
void f1(T f2, Foo &foo)
{
    f2(dynamic_caster{foo});
}
```

Comment: probably best to change the member to a reference and rename to `dynamic_deducer`, but *head explosion* Well done!

Comment: Will this also work if I pass a functor in as `f2`?

Comment: @Jack You already pass a functor. It will only work if the `operator()` of the functor is not a template, and probably also not overloaded.

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat. I couldn't actually get it to work with a function object, even when `operator()` wasn't overloaded. Not a big deal though! Thanks for your help again.

Comment: @Jack If you want to, share your code with a functor and I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, all bets are off if the operator() is overloaded (same limitation as my answer). @MooingDuck's answer seem to be the most elegant, except that one needs to write several case-by-case function. Well, who knew, templates and inheritance don't play nice together.

Comment: @alfC templates (compile time static dispatch) and inheritance (run time dynamic dispatch) don't place nice together. Generally most real world C++ uses very little passing around of base pointers, so it's usually not too much of an issue. The static-vs-dynamic also rears its head in Java when you try to get double-dispatch.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled to do this with deduced member function pointers for stateful lambdas, but eventually succeeded with SFINAE, which is more verbose, but works with stateful lambdas.

```
template<class T>
auto f1(T f2, Foo &foo) -> decltype(f2(dynamic_cast<Bar&>(foo))) {
    return f2(dynamic_cast<Bar&>(foo));
}
template<class T>
auto f1(T f2, Foo &foo) -> decltype(f2(dynamic_cast<Qux&>(foo))) {
    return f2(dynamic_cast<Qux&>(foo));
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61ceb268b0a5a443

Comment: This actually shows that the OP doesn't really need to deduce the type of the arguments, it needs to know if a certain argument works or not, which is a simpler task.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function template that deduces the argument type of a function pointer:

```
template<typename Ret, typename Arg>
Arg arg(Ret(*)(Arg));
```

and then use this to figure out the argument type of `f2` when doing the cast:

```
f2(dynamic_cast<decltype(arg(+f2))>(foo));
```

Note that the `+` when passing it as an argument to `arg` is to decay the lambda to a function pointer. This will only work when the lambda `f2` has exactly one argument, and doesn't have any captures.

Comment: I tried something similar, but "error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a pointer to member function" :( http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b809a24bbfb5d65.  Oh, you're converting the _lambda_ to a function pointer, which only works with stateless lambdas.

Comment: Really struggling to pull it off with stateful lambdas: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c306f985d7db9b8

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, not directly at least.
The problem is that an unconstrained type `T` (type of the function object), might have several overloads for `operator()`.
It might even be a templated operator.
That applies to a lambdas also (might even be an `auto` lambda).

In other words, even if there can be way, there is non enough introspection in C++ to do this right now.
And IMO even if you could it might indicate a flaw in the design.
(@MooingDuck's answer design seem more promising.)

So you have to change slightly what you are doing.
For example it seems that your lambdas are stateless, meaning that you can :

1. use a free function.
2. decay the (stateless) lambda to a function pointer (tip, lambdas decay (ab)using the `+` operation).

Once you accept that, it is easy from there;
you can use [Boost.TypeTraits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html) to deduce the (now uniquely) defined argument of the function.

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

struct Foo {
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
};
struct Bar : public Foo {};
struct Qux : public Foo {};

template<class T>
void f1(T f2, Foo &foo) {
  // dynamically cast foo to type of f2's argument
  f2(dynamic_cast<typename boost::function_traits<decltype(*f2)>::arg1_type&>(foo));
}

int main() {
  Bar bar;
  Qux qux;
  f1(+[](Bar &bar) {}, bar);
  f1(+[](Qux &qux) {}, qux); // works now!
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r1jf9n8Yf

If you want a more general solution you have define a protocol of function object with an internal or sfinae-detected "first argument". e.g. `struct F{using arg1_type = ...; auto operator()(arg1_type) const{...}};`.